# How to fix internal error updating maven project for PMD

Tags: eclipse, maven, pmd

Whenever I right click my project and go to maven -> update project I get the following error message :
 [image]

How can I get rid of this ? I have gone into eclipse market place and tried to update/add/remove pmd and none of it is helping.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing this problem for a while and after a lots of struggle, i found the solution.

> I was having corrupted version of PMD plugin in my eclipse plugin
> folder.  Deleting the PMD plugin from my STS installation Directory
> worked for me.

I have also made a video for this solution and posted on YouTube. You can check the video in case it didn't solve Your problem. [Refer Video Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5d-Eo5Kysw)